# How to create a parameter of type PSafeArray?

Tags: c#, delphi, com, delphi-xe2, typelib

How to create a parameter of type PSafeArray?

I take the following error from C# COM library:

```
  SafeArray with range 65262 transfered to the method that requires array with range 1
```

`Delphi XE2` should call `C# COM library` procedure using `Generated RIDL` type-library with a parameter of type PSafeArray.

Delphi XE2 code:

```
  function GetObjects: PSafeArray;
  var
    aObjects: Variant;
  begin
    aObjects := VarArrayCreate([0, 2], varVariant);
    aObjects[0] := ADOConnection.ConnectionObject;
    aObjects[1] := CashConnection;
    aObjects[2] := Self as IDispatch;
    Result := PSafeArray(TVarData(aObjects).VArray);
  end;

  ICompiler.Execute('MainNameSpace', 'MainClass', 'MainMethod', GetObjects);
```

C# COM library code:

```
void Execute(string Namespace, string ClassName, string MethodName, Object[] Objects);

void ICSCompiler.Execute(string Namespace, string ClassName, string MethodName, Object[] Objects)
{
  System.Type _type = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType(Namespace + "." + ClassName);
  System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
  System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod(MethodName);
  mi.Invoke(obj, new Object[] { Objects });
}
```

Generated RIDL code:

```
HRESULT _stdcall Execute([in] BSTR Namespace, [in] BSTR ClassName, [in] BSTR MethodName, [in] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) Objects);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first thing i can remember is `SafeArrayCreate`.
have a look at '[mysteries of PSafeArray](http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/)'

Answer (score 3):

This code works fine:

```
  function GetObjects: PSafeArray;
  var
    aBounds: array [0..0] of TSafeArrayBound;
    aObjects: PSafeArray;
    aIndex: Integer;
    aConnectionObject: OleVariant;
    aCashConnection: OleVariant;
    aScript: OleVariant;
  begin
    aBounds[0].lLbound   := 0;
    aBounds[0].cElements := 3;
    aObjects := SafeArrayCreate(varVariant, 1, @aBounds);
    aIndex := 0;
    aConnectionObject := ADOConnection.ConnectionObject;
    OleCheck(SafeArrayPutElement(aObjects, aIndex, aConnectionObject));
    aIndex := 1;
    aCashConnection := CashConnection;
    OleCheck(SafeArrayPutElement(aObjects, aIndex, aCashConnection));
    aIndex := 2;
    aScript := Self as IDispatch;
    OleCheck(SafeArrayPutElement(aObjects, aIndex, aScript));
    Result := aObjects;
  end;
```